# Querying media asset in module

Tags: assets, modules

I'm learning to write my own modules, so there's a lot that I still don't know. I have looked at other modules/plugins, videos, but I arrived at a dead end.

I'm writing a module that generates formatted, responsive html tags. The module sets a function that can be invoked from within a template --this is working already. The main arguments it takes are the entry object (`entry`), the image field handle (`fieldHandle`) that needs to be queried, and the desired image transforms (`transforms` array) that are required.

With that I want to obtain the image loaded to the field, and access the urls of the transforms.

I was able to get this to work on a macro, but I'm having a hard time with how to do the same from within a module.

If anyone has an example or suggestions it would be really appreciated.

Thank you

NOTE: just in case, I'm not interested in assets bundles associated with the module. I'm trying to query an asset from a entry uploaded though the back end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the field in the entry by using the normal array syntax, `$entry[$fieldHandle]`. Depending on whether or not the field is eager-loaded,  this will now be either an ElementQuery, which you can run `->all()` on, or an array of assets.

When you have the asset, you can use `$asset->getUrl($transform)` to get the URL to a transformed image.

```
use craft\elements\db\ElementQuery;

...

$elements = $entry[$fieldHandle];
$assets = ($elements instanceof ElementQuery) ? $elements->all() : $elements;

if (is_array($assets) && !empty($assets)) {
    foreach ($assets as $asset) {
        foreach ($transforms as $transform) {
            $transformedUrl = $asset->getUrl($transform);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear André Elvan, thank you so much for your generous input. this is exactly what I was looking for. I finished the module I was creating and it all is working very well. Very much appreciated.